# Singleton class not updating data on UICollectionViewCell’s with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I am not sure if this is correct way to say this but I have been trying to get data onto ColectionViewCell but it doesn't seem to show all of them. This question follows up from [Cards are not displaying different data. Koloda/Yalantis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47383253/cards-are-not-displaying-different-data-koloda-yalantis?noredirect=1#comment81719921_47383253). It appears that the framework requires a different method of applying data to the index but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Here is how my class looks:

```
import SwiftyJSON

class Person {

    var firstName: String?


    init(json: JSON) {
        self.firstName = json["first_name"].stringValue
    }
}
```

and here is my singleton that manages the `Person` class:

```
class PersonManager {

    static let shared = PersonManager()
    private init() {}

    var persons = [Person]()

    func removeAll() {
        persons.removeAll()
    }

    func addPerson(_ person: Person) {
        persons.append(person)
    }
}
```

And here is how I try to call the data *after* it has been **fetched** and **initialised** and **appended**:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

  let person = PersonManager.shared.persons[kolodaView.currentCardIndex]
  //Returns the first persons first name as it is supposed to
  cell.textLabel?.text = person.firstName
}
```

The data exists as it counts the number of person in my database. But it keeps on returning the first person for all the cards.

**Update:**

Using Firebase I am fetching the user data and then appending it like this:

```
func fetchUser() {
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")
    databaseRef.observe( .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            guard let snapshot = child as? DataSnapshot else { continue }
            let person = Person(from: snapshot)
            self.person = person
            PersonManager.shared.addPerson(person)
        }
        self.kolodaView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: After reading the comments, I guess you  should also make sure that the persons array holds different values.

Comment: It would really help if you can share the append code.

Comment: @OverD please see updated answer

Comment: @PuneetSharma when I print out `let person = PersonManager.shared.persons[indexPath.row] ` I get the same user every time it loops through my array.

Comment: Remove self.person = person and you should be in business

Comment: @Chace: print PersonManager.shared.persons after your for loop and check if they contain objects with same values or not

Comment: @PuneetSharma when I run a breakpoint and print `            PersonManager.shared.persons` I get different values, however it is not showing on the different cards. It just displaying the first result.

Comment: @OverD this does not seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @PuneetSharma if I try PersonManager.shared.persons.count at the `numberOfItemsInSection` I get the result I want but they are all on one card, rather than behind one another. Have you worked with Koloda library before?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your function as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

  let person = PersonManager.shared.persons[indexPath.row]
  //Returns the first persons first name as it is supposed to
  cell.textLabel?.text = person.firstName
}
```

The problem is that your variable `kolodaView.currentCardIndex` is always `0`, it will never show other results but the first in the set.

`indexPath.row` is meant to be used to control this index you need.

Comment: It keeps printing out `0`. `And do you mean `let person = PersonManager.shared.persons[indexPath.row]`? Because this does the same thing.

Comment: Exactly. This variable keeps track of the index to make your `CollectionView`. As the value of `kolodaView.currentCardIndex` is always `0`, it will never show other results but the first in the set.

Comment: So how do I get the collectionView to show other result?

Comment: Are you using a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView` to show your data?

Comment: Apologies it's` UICollectionView`, please see the updated question title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159354/discussion-between-juniorgarcia-and-chace).

Comment: It's strange but it seems like only until the third card does the data then change to the next person. But I'm not sure why as I'm not reloading the data anywhere else other than after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try indexPath.item, not row(That's for UITableView)

And make sure

> let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:
>   "cell", for: indexPath)

cell is not nil. You should print every cells.If it's nil, you can't put your data in a nil UICollectionViewCell.
So add code

> if(cell == nil) cell = [UICollectionViewCell new];

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return PersonManager.shared.persons.count
}
```

And in cellForItem you should use `indexPath.row` instead of `kolodaView.currentCardIndex` unless this is really what you need(very weird).
If so, check if PersonManager append same Person every time, which gives you only your first item every time. Double check it, because there is no another reason